# Iterating through the regex find

Tags: java, regex

```
Input-> Input!RC + Calc!R[1]C[1]
```

In Output I want to operate on these :

```
RC and R[1]C[1]
```

My attempt :

```
private static void findMatch(String formula) {
         Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\W(R(\\[(.+?)\\])?C(\\[(.+?)\\]))")
         .matcher(formula);
        // Matcher m = Pattern.compile(
        // "\\W(R(\\[(.+?)\\])?C) | \\W(R(\\[(.+?)\\])?C(\\[(.+?)\\]))")
        //  .matcher(formula);
        for (; m.find(); m.reset(formula)) {
            System.out.println(m.group(3));
        }

    }
```

It does not look for the second pattern as well it goes into infinite loops.

Whats wrong with this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
String formula = "Input!RC + Calc!R[1]C[1]";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\W(R(\\[(.+?)\\])?C(\\[(.+?)\\])?)").matcher(formula);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
RC
R[1]C[1]
```

The main change here is how the loop works, what I have above is the typical way for iterating over matches of a pattern.  I am also printing `m.group(1)` instead of `m.group(3)` because it is the first group that will contain the entire match except for the `!`, which I think is what you want.

The only change to your regex here was adding the `?` after the second `(\\[(.+?)\\])` group to make it optional.

Comment: I have only one concern with this : when I am trying to replace a particular group, say R[1]C, it also replaces part for R[1]C[1] which I do not want and gives erroraneous output. what do u think, how can I handle such situation ?

Comment: You need to write your regex such that it only matches the strings you want to replace.  If you want to replace `R[1]C` and not `R[1]C[1]` then you should change the `(\\[(.+?)\\])?` after the `C` to `(?!\\[(.+?)\\])`.  This is a negative lookahead which means "fail the match if the next characters in the string match `\\[(.+?)\\]`".

Answer (score 3):

If you look at this piece of code:

```
for (; m.find(); m.reset(formula)) {
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

For every loop, it calls successively `m.reset(formula)`, resetting the matcher so that it starts at 0, then `m.find()`, which look for the next match in the string. Since you called `reset()` before, the next match is the first match. Therefore you have an infinite loop.

If you want to find all matches in the string, simply write:

```
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```